# Linux system rebooting automatically every 1 minute

Tags: boot

Whenever I power up my Linux system, it starts and reboots continuously. All I can see is the logo.

---

i have some details but i cann't understand please help and the details are below

```
UBIFS: recovery completed
UBIFS: mounted UBI device 0, volume 0, name "data"
UBIFS: file system size:   278562816 bytes (272034 KiB, 265 MiB, 2159 LEBs)
UBIFS: journal size:       13934592 bytes (13608 KiB, 13 MiB, 108 LEBs)
UBIFS: media format:       w4/r0 (latest is w4/r0)
UBIFS: default compressor: lzo
UBIFS: reserved for root:  4952683 bytes (4836 KiB)
<30>udevd[1184]: starting version 3.2.5
<27>udevd[1184]: NAME="%k" is ignored, because it breaks kernel supplied names, please remove it fro
 /etc/udev/rules.d/usb.rules:1
<30>udevd[1191]: starting eudev-3.2.5
Checking partition consistency
done
Initializing random number generator... done.
Starting system message bus: done
Starting rpcbind: OK
Starting network: eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=0:00, irq=-1)
udhcpc: started, v1.27.2
udhcpc: sending discover
PHY: 0:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending select for 192.168.80.1
udhcpc: lease of 192.168.80.1 obtained, lease time 1468
/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script: Adding NTP server 192.168.66.11
restart: Unknown instance: 
OK
Starting nginx...
```

Comment: Can you boot from a Live USB ? Then check what are in the dmesg and messages logs in /var/log .. also other logs there might be interesting.

Comment: Is it 'continuously', or is it exactly 'every 1 minute'? Those point to different possible causes.

Comment: it is exactly 64 seconds fro the previous boot

Comment: i can't even log into the system

Comment: Can you press Shift while it reboots and get to a Grub screen?

Comment: the thing we are actually working with is a touch panel with linux OS

Comment: Does "linux OS" mean Ubuntu? Or something else? Exactly which version? Which kernel?

Comment: kernel version 2.6.35.3-0  and Linux flavour: Linux this is the detail i got from Serial print

Comment: Please specify what your Ubuntu version is.

Comment: this is not ubuntu UNAME command returns only :Linux when i trie to monitor it serially

Comment: I am sorry, a kernel version below 3.0 means this is not a supported version of Ubuntu and your question is off-topic here.

Comment: This site is only for Ubuntu.

Comment: => [Unix & Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

This particular problem is frequently caused by a bad RAM stick. If there is a bad RAM stick something in the onscreen boot messages will usually report it, however there might not be enough time to read all the boot messages because the computer reboots after 64 seconds. Even without reading the boot messages it is possible to troubleshoot this problem by removing the RAM sticks one at a time if there are more than one RAM sticks, and testing if the computer is able to boot normally when one RAM stick is removed.

If you have successfully found a bad RAM stick, the next thing to do is to remove the RAM stick from the computer, and take it with you to the computer store when you go to buy a replacement RAM stick to make sure that your new RAM stick will be compatible with the old one(s).