# Memory drops from 32 GB to 16 GB after freezing and restarting

Tags: ram

My Ubuntu 20.04 OS has 4x8GB DDR3 RAM that's worked fine since 2013. Recently it froze. After restarting "Settings > About" showed 16 GB. I switched the memory sticks in slots A0 & A1, and A2 & A3. The memory came back to 32 GB, but it froze a day later, and dropped back to 16 GB. Slot A1 on the motherboard has one latch broken (of two), but it hasn't been a problem. I'm not sure how to diagnose if a memory stick has failed, and if so, which one.

Output of `dmidecode -t memory`

```
# dmidecode 3.2 Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs. SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 5, 24 bytes Memory Controller Information   Error Detecting Method: 64-bit ECC  Error Correcting Capabilities:      None    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave  Maximum Memory Module Size: 4096 MB     Maximum Total Memory Size: 16384 MB     Supported Speeds:       70 ns       60 ns       50 ns   Supported Memory Types:         Standard        DIMM    Memory Module Voltage: 2.9 V    Associated Memory Slots: 4      0x0006      0x0007      0x0008      0x0009  Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:      None

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 6, 12 bytes Memory Module Information   Socket Designation: A0  Bank Connections: 1     Current Speed: 53 ns    Type: Other Unknown EDO     Installed Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)    Enabled Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)  Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 6, 12 bytes Memory Module Information   Socket Designation: A1  Bank Connections: 2     Current Speed: 53 ns    Type: Other Unknown EDO     Installed Size: 8192 MB (Double-bank Connection)    Enabled Size: 8192 MB (Double-bank Connection)  Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 6, 12 bytes Memory Module Information   Socket Designation: A2  Bank Connections: 3     Current Speed: 53 ns    Type: Other Unknown EDO     Installed Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)    Enabled Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)  Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 6, 12 bytes Memory Module Information   Socket Designation: A3  Bank Connections: 4     Current Speed: 53 ns    Type: Other Unknown EDO     Installed Size: 8192 MB (Double-bank Connection)    Enabled Size: 8192 MB (Double-bank Connection)  Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 16, 15 bytes Physical Memory Array  Location: System Board Or Motherboard   Use: System Memory  Error Correction Type: None     Maximum Capacity: 16 GB     Error Information Handle: Not Provided  Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 17, 27 bytes Memory Device  Array Handle: 0x0023    Error Information Handle: Not Provided  Total Width: 64 bits    Data Width: 64 bits     Size: 4096 MB   Form Factor: DIMM   Set: None   Locator: A0     Bank Locator: Bank0/1   Type: Unknown   Type Detail: None   Speed: 1333 MT/s    Manufacturer: None  Serial Number: None     Asset Tag: None     Part Number: None

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 17, 27 bytes Memory Device  Array Handle: 0x0023    Error Information Handle: Not Provided  Total Width: 64 bits    Data Width: 64 bits     Size: 8192 MB   Form Factor: DIMM   Set: None   Locator: A1     Bank Locator: Bank2/3   Type: Unknown   Type Detail: None   Speed: 1333 MT/s    Manufacturer: None  Serial Number: None     Asset Tag: None     Part Number: None

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 17, 27 bytes Memory Device  Array Handle: 0x0023    Error Information Handle: Not Provided  Total Width: 64 bits    Data Width: 64 bits     Size: 4096 MB   Form Factor: DIMM   Set: None   Locator: A2     Bank Locator: Bank4/5   Type: Unknown   Type Detail: None   Speed: 1333 MT/s    Manufacturer: None  Serial Number: None     Asset Tag: None     Part Number: None

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 17, 27 bytes Memory Device  Array Handle: 0x0023    Error Information Handle: Not Provided  Total Width: 64 bits    Data Width: 64 bits     Size: 8192 MB   Form Factor: DIMM   Set: None   Locator: A3     Bank Locator: Bank6/7   Type: Unknown   Type Detail: None   Speed: 1333 MT/s    Manufacturer: None  Serial Number: None     Asset Tag: None     Part Number: None
```

Comment: Yes, it's either memory or the slot (most likely). What it isn't is the OS.

Comment: If the RAM dropped; almost certainly it's the BIOS/uEFI firmware that decided it was *faulty* & thus ignored it. How the RAM appears to the OS is determined by your hardware & firmware combination; so why ask here?

Comment: @guiverc This is about using Linux for diagnostics and repair. It could help other members of AskUbuntu. So I think it's on topic.

Comment: Broken latches are very bad for the RAM.  What happens from a broken latch is that the RAM CANNOT seat properly in the socket and can come loose over time from vibrations caused by fans, walking around in the room, bumps, etc.  I had a video card where the front edge to the PCI-E slot was missing the clip.  I too thought the same as you that it wouldn't be an issue.  Any bump to the case would cause my system to freeze and I would have to hard power cycle the system to bring it back up.  I ended up finding the clip around and reinstalled it.  I have not had an issue since.

Comment: One other thing, if your RAM is paired off it may not see the matching pair when the memory fails in the broken slot.  I am not saying that the RAM is bad in the broken slot, but some boards in Dual Channel Memory may not show the second stick when it cannot see the first one.  Either run without the paired sticks or get your motherboard fixed or replaced so that the RAM will be seated correctly.  Or you can try running in Single Channel Mode for hopefully 24GB of RAM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux system rebooting automatically every 1 minute](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143736/linux-system-rebooting-automatically-every-1-minute)